# Are sequences faster than vectors for searching in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am kind of new using data structures in haskell besides of Lists. My goal is to chose one container among `Data.Vector`, `Data.Sequence`, `Data.List`, etc ... My problem is the following:

I have to create a sequence (mathematically speaking). The sequence starts at 0. In each iteration two new elements are generated but only one should be appended based in whether the first element is already in the sequence. So in each iteration there is a call to `elem` function (see the pseudo-code below).

```
appendNewItem :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
appendNewItem acc = let firstElem  = someFunc
                        secondElem = someOtherFunc
                        newElem    = if firstElem `elem` acc 
                                        then secondElem
                                        else firstElem
                    in  acc `append` newElem

sequenceUptoN :: Int -> [Integer]
sequenceUptoN n = (iterate appendNewItem [0]) !! n
```

Where `append` and `iterate` functions vary depending on which colection you use (I am using lists in the type signature for simplicity).

The question is: Which data structure should I use?. Is `Data.Sequence` faster for this task because of the Finger Tree inner structure?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `Data.Sequence` in conjunction with `Data.Set`. The `Sequence` to hold the sequence of values and the `Set` to track the collection.

`Sequence`, `List`, and `Vector` are all structures for working with values where the position in the structure has primary importance when it comes to indexing. In lists we can manipulate elements at the front efficiently, in sequences we can manipulate elements based on the log of the distance the closest end, and in vectors we can access any element in constant time. Vectors however, are not that useful if the length keeps changing, so that rules out their use here.

However, you also need to lookup a certain value within the list, which these structures don't help with. You have to search the whole of a list/sequence/vector to be certain that a new value isn't present. `Data.Map` and `Data.Set` are two of the structures for which you define an index value based on `Ord`, and let you lookup/insert in `log(n)`. So, at the cost of memory usage you can lookup the presence of `firstElem` in your Set in `log(n)` time and then add `newElem` to the end of the sequence in constant time. Just make sure to keep these two structures in synch when adding or taking new elements.

Comment: Right. Although I'd remark that for small-ish sequences, even a brute-force search through an unboxed vector is often faster than a lookup in `Data.Map` due to its much better cache locality. And a binary search through an _ordered_ vector gives the best of both worlds. The only real problem with vectors is the creation.

Comment: Interesting. Helpful for me, and intermediate Haskeler, but I think this might be a little much for someone new to haskell data structures.

Comment: Interesting approach. I wil give It a try!

Answer (score 6):

No, sequences are not faster for searching. A `Vector` is just a flat chunk of memory, which gives generally the best lookup performance. If you want to optimise searching, use `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. (The normal, “boxed” variant is also pretty good, but it actually contains only *references* to the elements in the flat memory-chunk, so it's not quite as fast for lookups.)

However, because of the flat memory layout, `Vector`s are *not* good for (pure-functional) appending: basically, whenever you add a new element, the whole array must be copied so as to not invalidate the old one (which somebody else might still be using). If you need to append, `Seq` is a pretty good choice, although it's not as fast as *destructive* appending: for maximum peformance, you'll want to pre-allocate an uninitialized [`Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable.MVector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Mutable.html) of the required size, populate it using the `ST` monad, and freeze the result. But this is much more fiddly than purely-functional alternatives, so unless you need to squeeze out every bit of performance, `Data.Sequence` is the way to go. If you *only* want to append, but not look up elements, then a plain old list in reverse order would also do the trick.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your answer. I still need to learn a lot. I'll go with Data.Sequence. I didn't know Vectors must be copy when appending.